CardView rounded corner shows white colors
I have a card view
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorCard"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
app:strokeColor="@color/colorBorder"
app:strokeWidth="1dp"

But white color can be seen in the rounded corners.

I used
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"

But it doesn't matter
Because it must have a background.

hi, do you have elevation enabled? that seems like a shadow of it.

hi, no elevation is 0, and also it must have a stroke 1dp and color.

app:strokeWidth="0dp"


if you are adding this cardView in your general xml layouts then use the property:
android:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"

with this there won't have the white area around rounded corners.
but if you are using it as the root layout of your dialogs, then no matter what property you choose it still would have white area around rounded corners, for this case use the following line with the dialog object before calling dialog.show()
dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

ask question in comment if the problem still persists.
